# How to let component detect its hidden status in angular2?

Tags: angular, dart

I have two components, child component display status is controlling by the parent.  How to let child aware its parent is changed the hidden attribute?

```
// Parnet
@Component(selector: '[component-parent]',
    templateUrl: 'component-parent.html')
class ComponentParent {
    bool enableChild;
}

<div>
    <div component-child [hidden]="enableChild"></div>
</div>

// Child
@Component(selector: '[component-child]',
    templateUrl: 'component-child.html')
class ComponentChild {
    // How child aware not it is not hidden anymore?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component needs an `@Input()` with matching name to support `[xxx]="..."` binding:

```
@Component(selector: '[component-child]',
    templateUrl: 'component-child.html')
class ComponentChild {
  @Input()
  set hidden(bool val) {
    print(val);
  }
}
```